# How to display an Error message when logging in fails in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, validation, authentication, react-hooks, react-router

How to display an Error message when logging in fails in Reactjs.
I want to display the alert message 'Invalid Username or Password, Please try again.' when the user logs in fails on the page. How can I do that in Reactjs?

the code:

```
    login.js
export default function LogIn() {
    let history = useHistory();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        username: '',
        password: '',
    });

const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateFormData({
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
    });
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    axiosInstance
        .post(`token/`, {
            username: formData.username,
            password: formData.password,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh);
            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token');
                history.push("/home");
            
        });
};
return (
    <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
      <TextField
           margin="normal"
           required
           id="username"
           label="username"
           name="username"
           autoComplete="username"
           autoFocus
           onChange={handleChange}/>

      <TextField
        margin="normal"
        required
        name="password"
        label="password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        autoComplete="current-password"
        onChange={handleChange}/>
                        
         <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                 LOG IN
          </Button>            
          </Box>    
);}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your authentication logic that returns the authentication result?

Comment: I edited the code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you share what the `/token` POST response is if authentication fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use alert in javascript to show a dialog box also you can use this [Pakage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify)

to show alert or message to the user

> you can use this code to set error in state and show in label

```js
const [error,setError]=useState();
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    axiosInstance
        .post(`token/`, {
            username: formData.username,
            password: formData.password,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh);
            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token');
                history.push("/home");
            
        }, reason => {
  console.error(reason); // Error!
setError('Invalid Username or Password')
});
};
```

```js
return (
    <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
      <TextField
           margin="normal"
           required
           id="username"
           label="username"
           name="username"
           autoComplete="username"
           autoFocus
           onChange={handleChange}/>

      <TextField
        margin="normal"
        required
        name="password"
        label="password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        autoComplete="current-password"
        onChange={handleChange}/>
                        
         <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                 LOG IN
          </Button>  
         {error?<Label>{error}</Label>:null}          
          </Box>    
);
```